# Combined Chart with BarChart + LineChart onClickListener

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to use Combined Chart with BarChart and LineChart, but I would like to set the barChart as clickable only. Now if the click is near the line, the line's click fires, and not the Bar behind it (using stackedbars). Below is the code for the onClickListener (I had to check for the entry's type to avoid crash).

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        float val = 0;
        if (e instanceof BarEntry) {
            float[] vals = ((BarEntry) e).getYVals();
            if (vals != null) {
                val = vals[h.getStackIndex()];
            } else {
                val = e.getY();
            }
        } else {
            val = e.getY();
        }
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(((BarModel) e.getData()).getName() + " - " + val + "%");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                chart.highlightValues(null);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to set `lineData.setHighlightEnabled(false);`